# What are the versions of cpython which different implementations(jython/ironpython/pypy/etc) are roughly compatible with

Tags: python, version, incompatibility, language-implementation

i.e. jython(or other implementation) version x.y is roughly equivalent to cpython version a.b

Please list version of alternative implementation, and feel free to list multiple versions 
so this list will still be useful in the future. If possible list any large incompatibilities 
(with cpython) for each version excluding things like c interface and relying or reference counting.

Comment: The most reliable way is to just look at the website of the implementation in question - that's also always up to date ;) Plus, AFAIK most of those implementations use precisely the version number of the CPython version they're compatible with.

Answer (score 3):

The most popular alternative implementations are [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/), [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) and [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/).

Jython currently implements Python 2.5.2 support for 2.6 is on their roadmap.

- Partial support for ctypes
- Does not support C API

IronPython implements Python 2.7.1.

- Partial support for ctypes
- Does not support C API, although [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) attempts to add a compatibility layer

PyPy implements Python 2.7.1.

- Good ctypes support
- Alpha/beta C API support

Stackless Python supports 2.7.1 and 3.2 currently.

- Supports nearly everything CPython would

They all do a good job implementing the core language, but have differing support for the standard library.